# Django: combining a DetailView and a form on the same view

Tags: python, django

Is there a way I can combine a detailview and a form into the same view? I'm making a rental system where when a user clicks on a particular house, he will be directed to a detailview page of that house. And after viewing the details of the house he intends to rent, he will fill a form while still on the detailview page then the form will be saved in the database.

Here's what I have so far

views.py

```
class HouseDetailView(DetailView):
model = House
template_name = 'Home/detail.html'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(HouseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['house_list'] = House.objects.all()
    return context

def Callback (request):
form = CallbackForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CallbackForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Callback Submission Successful.')
    return redirect('Home')
context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'Home/callback.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import (
       HouseView,
       HouseDetailView,
       )

      from . import views

      urlpatterns = [
    path('Home/', views.Home, name='Home'),
    path('SignUp/', views.SignUp, name='SignUp'),
    path('Login/', views.Login, name='Login'),
    path('house/', HouseView.as_view(), name='house'),
    path('callback/', views.Callback, name='callback'),
    path('Logout/', views.Login, name='Logout'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', HouseDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
      ]

forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import House, Lease, Agent, Customer, Callback

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class CallbackForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Callback
    fields = ['Username', 'Phone', 'email', 'HouseId']
```

Templates
lease.html

```
{% extends "Home/Base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="box-element1">
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div id="user-info">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h3 id="form-title">Personal Details</h3>
        </div>
                                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" >
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Phone" >
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> 
    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="HouseId" class="form-control" name="HouseId" >
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" 
 name="Lease" value="Get a Call Back">
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
{{form.errors}}                      
    <script>
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
            form_fields[1].placeholder='Username..';
            form_fields[2].placeholder='Phone..';
            form_fields[3].placeholder='email..';
            form_fields[4].placeholder='HouseId..';

            for (var field in form_fields){
                form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
                }
    </script>
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<br>
<div class="box-element hidden" id="payment-info">
<small>Paypal Options</small>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{house.image.url}}">
                <div class="box-element-house">
                    <h6><strong> {{house.HouseId}}</strong></h6>
                    <h6><strong>Type: {{house.HouseType}}</strong></h6>
                    <h6><strong>Location: {{house.Location}}</strong></h6>
                    <h6><strong>Status: {{house.Status}}</strong></h6>
                    <h6><strong>Rent: Ksh.{{house.Rent|floatformat:2}}</strong></h6>
                    <a  btn-outline-success ></a>
               </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

The image below is how the page is supposed to look like
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gTy2awJU2GCZYhCHauhOgB5DIPQaTLYw/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add any additional context (like form) to your view just override `get_context_data` method on DetailView and add it to your template's context

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['callback_form'] = CallBackForm(initial={'HouseId': self.object.id})
    return context
```

then you should of course display it somehow on your page in a

```
<form method='post' action={% url 'your-callback-from-handling-url' %}>
    {{ callback_form.as_p }} 
    <button type='submit'...>...</button>
</form>
```

and from then you can use another django's built-in View - `CreateView` which will under the 'your-callback-from-handling-url' url

```
class CallBackCreateView(CreateView):
    model = CallBack
    fields = ['Username', 'Phone', 'email', 'HouseId']
    success_url = 'url-to-redirect-after-creating-the-CallBack'
```

This will automatically create your CallBack instance - of course this needs some polishing like error handling and so on. Please read the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)